# How is loop information encoded in FLAC files?

Tags: audio, compression

I'm trying to convert `.wav` files (samples for a sampled instrument) into FLAC format.  The `.wav` files have loop information in the `smpl` chunk.  I understand that various sample players support loops in FLAC files.  However, I can't find a converter that converts `.wav` to `.flac` and preserves the loop information.  I could code it myself (say, by postprocessing results from `SoX`), but can't find any information on how loops are encoded in FLAC files.

I'm using this for sampled instruments with hundreds of `.wav` files and so need to be able to do batch processing.

Sorry if this is the wrong forum.  It's not quite stackoverflow or sounddesign.

Comment: The information is in the flac file format specifications. Look up seekpoints or cues based on what suits better for your purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is, "the same way it's kept in .wav files."  FLAC uses the same RIFF "chunk" structure as WAV.  The WAV file format has a chunk for use by samplers, which includes looping information.  I found I could simply copy that chunk from the WAV file and append it to the FLAC file and it worked (for anything that supported loops in FLAC files, which isn't everything -- for example linuxsampler does not, due to a library it uses not supporting it yet.)

Better yet, the `flac` application has a `--keep-foreign-metadata` option that does the trick without my having to code anything.